# Screen capturing/recording in android for un rooted devices

Tags: android, android-screen

As part of one of my application's requirements, I need to capture the screenshot at run time. I know this is possible for rooted devices. But I need to do this for normal devices(which are not rooted) also. With in our application, I am able to capture the screenshot. But when I minimize the app and try to capture, it's not allowing to do.

If any one has any idea on this, please share with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using adb, you can use screen capture or record in kitkat. but in application it's impossible.

Comment: You can't do this within an app for security reasons.  Its to prevent you from doing malicious things, like taking a screenshot when someone's typing in their password to try and steal it.  There's no method to do it, and if you find a loophole that allows it Google will close it.